# bottom constraints to superview dont work with 3.5 layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have constraints set in interfacebuilder that have some UIViews near the bottom of the screen.  They have constraints set to have their bottom, leading and trailing edge attached to superview.

However when I view the xib within a 3.5 simulator the views are off screen(below) instead of maintaining that explicity set distance from the bottom of the 'superview'

This view is made in a xib, and then I load the xib into a view controller in code.

So my question is how do I get the bottom and top layouts to apply to these buttons inside this seperate xib I have?  The buttons seem to be hard coded to layout depending on the design size of iphone 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't the buttons, but the parent view which contains them.  Make sure its constraints are set to adjust to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Well Im just adding the instantiated xib in code to the viewcontrollers.view but I cant set the top and bottom layouts on that viewcontroller.view...

Comment: I had to set the frame of the xib to its parents bounds.